# Selenium / Java: Alternative methods to 'isDisplayed()' for verifying if an element is present or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It seems that `.isDisplayed()` method is not working in our framework.

It works fine if the element is displayed in the application. If not, it is throwing `Null Pointer Exception`. So, just wanted to know if there is any other method to verify if the element is present and write if-else condition accordingly.

Comment: Please add usage example

Comment: It is recommended that you **ALWAYS** present version information for your testing tool-suite (Selenium version, driver type & version, framework type & version).
Else, you are going to receive shitty suggestions that might not even work for your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose your code in Try and catch block and maintain condition if element display then perform your actions. If element not display then it will through the exception which will be handled by catch block.

```
 try
{
      if(usersname.isDisplayed())
    {
        System.out.println("Already Login");

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{            
        new UserLogin(driver).doLogin(TestDataComman.username, TestDataComman.password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if element is present or not by following code :

```
driver.findElements( By.id("...") ).size() != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way other than using isDisplayd() method is:

Count the number of elements and check whether it is greater than zero

Code snippet:

```
boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("your selector")).size() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you can create your own custom method to verify if a element is present on the page or not

```
    public boolean IsElementPresent(String locatorKey) {
    List<WebElement> e = null;
    e = driver.findElements(By.id(locatorKey));

    if (e.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try following method to check if the element exists:

```
  public boolean isPresent(By locator_of_your_element){

  List <WebElement> yourElement = driver.findElements(your locator here);

  if (yourElement.size()!=0){

      return true;
    }
    else{

     return false;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting null pointer exception is, **isDisplayed()** method assumes that element is already present and then checks if it's visible or not.

This is what I do to check if element is present or not?

```
public boolean isElementExist(By element, int timeout){
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    try{
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));

    }catch (TimeoutException te){
        return null;
    }
}
```

you can call this method to get element Object and then check if it's displayed or not. or better you can wait until element is visible using following code.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(a)));
```